# How to use EF code first migration to generate scripts from powershell

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a need to email our DBA when a deployment, that utilizes EF6 code-based migrations, goes out. I am able to use the migrate.exe tool with the verbose flag, through powershell, to get the scripts but each command is truncated after 10222 characters. This usually only effects the model hash for the migrationHistory. Does anyone know of a way to generate the full sql script for EF6 migrations through Powershell

thanks
T

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that migrate.exe is wrapping the [toolingfacade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.design.toolingfacade(v=vs.113).aspx) class So I created the object passing in the required variables as well as setting the verbosedelegate. The nice thing about this is that I could run the updatescript function instead if I just wanted to get the sql scripts

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("EntityFramework.dll") | Out-Null
$con = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo -ArgumentList @("constring", "System.Data.SqlClient")
$tools = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade -ArgumentList @("dbcondllname", "dbcondllname",$null,"workingdr",$null,$null,$con)
$tools.LogVerboseDelegate = {param($sql)
    Write-Verbose $sql -verbose #dumps the sql to RM log
}
$tools.Update($null,$false)
```

Comment: any change you can clarify what is `dbcondllname`?

Comment: dbcondllname is the dll name that the db context residues in, I believe the second argument is where the migrations are stored which for this case was the same dll

Comment: Here is the link to the class constructor for more clarity. [ToolingFacade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.design.toolingfacade(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: There is also $tools.ScriptUpdate.  If you call Update it also applies the migration.